# Prove Algebraically .... $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n\binom{n-1}{k-1}}k$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am asked to prove the following identity: $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n\binom{n-1}{k-1}}k$

I have tried to use the definition $\binom{n}{k}:= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ and expand it from there but I get stuck.

Comment: Usually, it's easier to start from the most complicated expression (in this case, the right hand side of the equality) and simplify it.

Comment: @BernardMassé In this case, I disagree; the identity follows readily from the fundamental recursion of binomial coefficients. But in general that is a good idea :)

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\binom{n}{k}
&=
\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\\
&=
\frac{n}{k}\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)! }\\
&=
\frac{n}{k}\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!\left(n-k-1+1\right)! } \\
&=
\frac{n}{k}\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!\left(n-1-(k-1)\right)! } \\
&=
\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$ \binom nk = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}k = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \frac{n-k}k\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\frac nk\binom{n-1}{k-1}, $$
as
$$\binom{n-1}k = \frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-1-k)!}=\frac{(n-1)!(n-k)}{k(k-1)!(n-k)(n-1-k)!}. $$